# String wouldn't print itself in C

Tags: c, string, hex, ascii-art

I'm trying to format an ASCII-Art style string with strtok. When I try to run my program through my IDE it is actually printing my string which is in hexadecimal so I don't have to mess with all the backslashes in it. However when I try to run it in console (Ubuntu) it doesn't give anything back.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char pacmanText[] = { 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
                      0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
                      0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
                      0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0d, 
                      0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 
                      0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 
                      0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 
                      0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 
                      0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x29, 0x20, 0x2f, 0x20, 
                      0x5f, 0x60, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 
                      0x27, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x60, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 0x20, 0x2f, 
                      0x20, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x27, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 
                      0x20, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2f, 0x20, 
                      0x28, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x28, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x7c, 
                      0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 
                      0x20, 0x28, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 
                      0x20, 0x7c, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
                      0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 
                      0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 
                      0x7c, 0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 
                      0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x0d, 0x0a
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    struct winsize w; 
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w); 

    char *pch = NULL; 

    pch = strtok(pacmanText, "\n"); 
    while (pch != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("%s", pch); 
        fflush(stdout); 

        pch = strtok(NULL, "\n"); 

    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

So can anyone tell me why it won't print me that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1. You need a null terminating character at the end of `pacmanText` for the reasons that [iharob talks about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950465/47453).
2. `strtok()` will modify the string such that the separator character is replaced by a `'\0'`. So you never print a newline in the entire program.

Let's fix these bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char pacmanText[] = {
    0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0d, 
    0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 
    0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 
    0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 
    0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x29, 0x20, 0x2f, 0x20, 
    0x5f, 0x60, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 
    0x27, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x60, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 0x20, 0x2f, 
    0x20, 0x5f, 0x60, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x27, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x5c, 
    0x20, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2f, 0x20, 
    0x28, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x28, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x7c, 
    0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 
    0x20, 0x28, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 
    0x20, 0x7c, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x5f, 
    0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x7c, 0x5f, 
    0x7c, 0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5f, 0x2c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x20, 
    0x7c, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x00
}; 

int main() { 
    char *pch = strtok(pacmanText, "\n"); 
    while (pch != NULL) { 
        printf("%s\n", pch); 
        pch = strtok(NULL, "\n"); 
    } 
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[1:08pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
 ____                                  
|  _ \ __ _  ___ _ __ ___   __ _ _ __  
| |_) / _` |/ __| '_ ` _ \ / _` | '_ \ 
|  __/ (_| | (__| | | | | | (_| | | | |
|_|   \__,_|\___|_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|
```

Comment: This answers the question, I just wish the OP explains the `strtok()`.

Comment: @iharob I answered why I need strtok below in your post!

Comment: @iPh1ps99 I already read that, and updated my answer. It makes sense, although you could declare the array as 2-dimensional and split each line in an array.

Comment: @iharob Yeah you are right but that would put more effort into every single string of those. It's not just the one with the pacman text in it :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `'\0'` terminator in your string, just add one more element to the array at it's end `0x00`, also your `strtok()` is splitting the lines properly, the problem is you miss the `'\n'` character at the end of the line, so just change this

```
printf("%s", pch);
```

to

```
printf("%s\n", pch);
```

but, there is no point in doing that. You can just use `printf("%s", pacmanText);`

So the fundamental problem is `strtok()` it replaces the delimiter with `'\0'` so when you do this

```
printf("%s", pch);
```

you are not printing the delimiter.

Comment: That's actually not changing anything, but thanks for the answer

Comment: @iPh1ps99 It might not be changing anything, but passing the array as it was to `strtok` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @iPh1ps99 I don't see any `'\n'` characters in the array except at the end, what is the point of `strtok` then? is it that the data is incomplete?

Comment: I just, used `printf()` on it, and it worked perfectly, why are you using `strtok()` can you please explain?

Comment: 0x0a is actually '\n' and there are more than one

Comment: I know, there is only one of them at the end, Oh nevermind I just saw others, still, why are you using `strtok()`?

Comment: Well my problem is I actually wanted to store all the lines seperated in an array so I can later on center the whole output each line